# How would I make my player move with on screen button?

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine

As the title says, how do I do that in Unity with C#? I have tried some things myself, but with the things I tried, my player always glitched out of the screen. So I was wondering how it should be done.
http://pastebin.com/q60xgvZM - PlayerScript.cs
http://pastebin.com/AuHzYhtH - MoveScript.cs (I don't know if this one if useful for you guys)
And here is my GameButtons.cs where I was trying to make the buttons in (don't mind the comments. I like to copy and paste):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GameButtons : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnGUI()
  {
    const int buttonWidth = 60;
    const int buttonHeight = 60;

    // Draw a button to start the game
    if (
      GUI.Button(
        // Center in X, 2/3 of the height in Y
        new Rect(
          Screen.width / 5 - (buttonWidth / 2),
          (3 * Screen.height / 4) - (buttonHeight / 2),
          buttonWidth,
          buttonHeight
        ),
        "UP"
      )
    )
    {
      // On Click, load the first level.
      // "Stage1" is the name of the first scene we created.
      speed.x += Vector2.up * 10;
    }
        if (
      GUI.Button(
        // Center in X, 2/3 of the height in Y
        new Rect(
         Screen.width / 5 - (buttonWidth / 2),
          (13 * Screen.height / 14) - (buttonHeight / 2),
          buttonWidth,
          buttonHeight
        ),
        "DOWN"
      )
    )
    {
      // On Click, load the first level.
      // "Stage1" is the name of the first scene we created.
      speed.y += Vector2.down * 10;
    }
        if (
      GUI.Button(
        // Center in X, 2/3 of the height in Y
        new Rect(
          Screen.width / 8 - (buttonWidth / 2),
          (5 * Screen.height / 6) - (buttonHeight / 2),
          buttonWidth,
          buttonHeight
        ),
        "LEFT"
      )
    )
    {
      speed.x += Vector2.left * 10;
    }
        if (
      GUI.Button(
        // Center in X, 2/3 of the height in Y
        new Rect(
          Screen.width / 4 - (buttonWidth / 2) + 24,
          (5 * Screen.height / 6) - (buttonHeight / 2),
          buttonWidth,
         buttonHeight
        ),
        "RIGHT"
      )
    )
    {
      // On Click, load the first level.
      // "Stage1" is the name of the first scene we created.
      speed.y += Vector2.right * 10;
    }
        if (
      GUI.Button(
        // Center in X, 2/3 of the height in Y
        new Rect(
          (Screen.width / 1) - (buttonWidth * 2) - 20,
          (5 * Screen.height / 6) - (buttonHeight / 2),
          buttonWidth,
          buttonHeight
        ),
        "FIRE"
      )
    )
    {
      // On Click, load the first level.
      // "Stage1" is the name of the first scene we created.
      Application.LoadLevel("ShootEmUp");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the scale of your scene?  Is it possible that the velocity is so high that the player is moving off-screen?

Incidentally, your "up" input is modifying x instead of y.

Comment: The scale of my camera is 1,1,1. My viewport rect is Width 1, Height 1 , if that helps any. And that's the problem, I don't know if the velocity is too high because I don't really know how high it is. About the up being x: it didn't really matter to me, first i wanted to see if it did something.

Comment: Ok, so in this case we don't really know the behavior of the system.  Try just doing "speed.x += Vector.left * 1" or "speed.x += Vector.left * 0.1f" and see what happens.

Comment: Then I get: The name 'vector' does not exist in the current context. When I do vector2 I get: 'UnityEngine.Vector2' does not contain a definition for 'left'. Vector3: Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'float' and 'UnityEngine.Vector3'

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I meant take your existing line and using "* 1" or "* 0.1f" instead of "* 10".  Slow it down and see if any motion causes your player to teleport off screen, or if it is just going too fast.

Comment: My original code modified is speed.y += Vector2.down * 1; But then I get: 'UnityEngine.Vector2' does not contain a definition for 'down'

Comment: Is it maybe possible to simulate the arrow keys being pressed? That would also be an option for me.